# Выборочная группировка (или группировка по группам)

Tags: php, mysql

Это выборка из базы по условиям:
Исходный массив:

```
0 : { group: "1", value: "4"}
1 : { group: "1", value: "4"}
2 : { group: "1", value: "8"}
3 : { group: "2", value: "2"}
4 : { group: "2", value: "8"}
5 : { group: "2", value: "8"}
```

Вопрос, возможно сгруппировать элементы запросом MySql,
при условии что группироватся могут только элементы value из своей группы (group)?

Конечным вариатом группировки должен быть такой массив:

```
0 : { group: "1", value: "4"}
2 : { group: "1", value: "8"}
3 : { group: "2", value: "2"}
4 : { group: "2", value: "8"}
```

Comment: Можно. Покажите исходный запрос.

Comment: Во внутрь групировки пишем `case when .... then .... else ... end`. Их можно вкладывать друг-в-друга (древовидно), - и сделать условную групировку любой сложности.

Comment: Звучит круто. А можно маленький примерчик?

Comment: `select distinct group, value from table`. Или, если вот то число которое перед скобками то же в БД и оно нужно, то элементарный group by по этим двум полям, а то поле перед скобками например min()

Comment: select distinct group, value - работает. Прочитал документацию по нему. Вроде всё просто и логично, но как именно distinct работает я пока не понял. Скажем если он выбирает уникальные group, то почему он не показал 2 записи, а 4 как нужно.

Comment: distinct выбирает не уникальную group а уникальное сочетание group, value

Comment: слово distinct относится ко всей записи. т.е. буквально "выбери уникальные записи". если хотя бы одно поле _из выбираемых_ отличается, значит оно уникально, показываем. если все до единого полей совпали - подавляем